# add new synonyms in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I created the synonym file (synonym.txt) in my index and it is already working correctly when I search for words that have synonyms.

However I have a question! If I need to add new synonyms in the file (synonym.txt), how do I make the new synonyms work? because when I add new synonyms it doesn't work, it only works the synonyms that already existed in the file (synonym.txt) when I created my index.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mark the synonym file as `"updateable": true`? Did you reload the search analyzers via `POST /myindex/_reload_search_analyzers`?

Comment: @jarmod my elasticsearch is version 7.2 and the command "_reload_search_analyzers" does not work because it only works in version 7.3

Comment: Apparently, prior to 7.3, in order to make changes to a synonym rule file visible to the index, you have to update the synonym file on all nodes, then close and reopen the index.

Comment: @jarmod I already closed and opened the index and it didn't work with the new synonyms